# Does Standard Deviation Increase/Decrease when Average Increases?

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

I have a mean(88) and standard deviation(6) of sample data from period 1, I have the mean(91) for period 2 data; the mean increases from period 1 to period 2. Additionally, I have sample data from period 2 where the mean is 93 and standard deviation is 3.

The data has a possible minimum value of 0 and maximum value of 100, although the actual range for the period 1 data is 55-100.It is also not normal, and it is right skewed.

Does the standard deviation decrease in this scenario, is it possible to estimate standard deviation for the population of period 2?

Comment: Not enough information. If you know sample sizes and the distribution family for these data (such as, gamma or lognormal) then one might be able to do a formal test. // If you have the data it might be possible to do a nonparametric test or a bootstrap procedure.

Comment: If the maximum is 100, you'd expect standard deviation would typically get smaller as the mean approached more closely to 100.